# Restoring a database using Azure service bus topics

Tags: sql-server, azure, c#-4.0, azureservicebus

My problem can be visualised as the producer-consumer problem. I want to restore a database on SQL-server. The producer side has the responsiblity of sending the records through Azure service bus topic. On the consumer side, I need to consume the message and then process it to the database. Assume the number of records to be around 20 million and minimum network latency.

Is it the best approach for restoring a database using a cloud technology?
If yes, what should be the best approach to process this much amount of data in an hour or two?
If No, suggest the suitable technology. Technology should be from Azure cloud offerings.

Comment: Short comment: depends on details, not enough info. E.g. is it a one time event vs. repeatable, how many objects / tables are in the DB, how big is each record / message, do they have to come in order and so on.

Comment: Assume a simplified scenario. We have only one table. Assume that each record is of 2kb. No order required. I think whether I have to do one time or repeatedly doesn't matter. I have already specified the time limit within which I should be able to do it. Assume no changes on db side when I am doing this process.

Comment: Azure Service Bus is not a database restoration / synchronization technology. It's a messaging technology. You should look for other technology options to achieve your goal.

Comment: @SeanFeldman can you suggest me some? I have found Azure data factory. Can you suggest any other alternatives?

Comment: @nizaamir I have no specific pointers. DB restoration sounds like an operation that should take place once you have the data. It's OK to build up your data with events over time, but if you got all the data and replying it with ASB sounds off. I can't offer a solution without understanding the details of this specific problem. Personally (based on what you've shared), I'd build up all the records in a store of some sort (table storage?) and "push" it when restoration is needed.